# ElasticSearch start up error - the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use;

Tags: elasticsearch, startup, elasticsearch-7

I have tried giving the following configurations in the elasticsearch.yaml file

`network.host: aa.bbb.ccc.dd` that being my  IPv4 Address
and `http.port: 9200`

The response to this is as follows when I try to run elasticsearch.bat on my windows machine:

`the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`

I am really not quite sure what to configure for the cluster initialization. The default values are  `discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]` and `cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]`

Comment: How many nodes master nodes will you be setting up in your cluster?

Comment: hay @OpsterESNinjaNishant , by n0,n1 and n2 you mean the IPV4 addresses of other client computers right ?

Comment: That can be value of `node.name` or IPv4 address  of other nodes (elastic instances running on other machine) as well as of self (if it fall in the same category).

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant .. by 'elastic instances running on other machine' you mean the machine trying to access the server machine must also have elastic search running in it?

Comment: No, by 'elastic instances running on other machine' I mean all those server machines that have elastic running on them and which should be the part of same cluster.

Comment: well I have just one that is the server. I want it to have remote access so others can access the search data. I tried what u told in the answer section, It dint work.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Sorry I dont use stackoverflow unless I have questions to ask. My apologies, I have upvoted your answer and marked it as the right one! Thanks! :)
The issue was sort of resolved with the node configurations also but yes, your answer is definitely better and it works! so marked it right!

Comment: @SSB lf you notice this is one of the most popular question on elasticsearch tag and have been viewed ~11K times :) so having the good content on it, makes it more useful to community :)

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja Its all about better answers. Whatever is the better answer is the answer. And again I am replying a whole month later because I don't login too often. Thanks for your answer! I am sure its helping many :) ;)

Comment: @SSB, you are right, and appreciate your actions :)

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja could you please share your thoughts on this one ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897286/can-i-filter-an-array-in-elastic

Answer (score 235, accepted):

In short, if you are running Elasticsearch locally(single node) or just with a single node on the cloud then just use below config  in your `elasticsearch.yml` to avoid the production check, and to make it work, more info about this config in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426167/4039431) answer:

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

Comment: This should be  in the default configuration, commented at least.

Comment: @Enerccio I am just curious why you think so, I am being programmer myself have opinion that great software product can't be made without great programmers :)

Comment: @Enerccio I am hoping you also faced the same issue which bring you to my answer :) hope it was helpful to you and resolved your issue :)

Comment: If you are trying to run elasticsearch from docker, like I did, then you should pass the next env variable - `-e "discovery.type=single-node"`. Taken from official docs https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch

Comment: Or you can add in docker yaml file:
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node

Comment: What a legend, it's a shame it's not a comment in the configuration file to help

Comment: @Oliver you are right, it should have been part of the configuration file

Answer (score 39):

This is the configuration I did since I had only one machine that had the Elastic Search db in it (1 node Only).

```
node.data : true
network.host : 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts : []
cluster.initial_master_nodes : []
```

Comment: I've also tried with `discovery.seed_hosts : ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]` and works great. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

- I have also faced the same issue with the `elastic-search 7.6.2` version. The solution of the above-mentioned problem is, you just need to either add `"discovery.seed_hosts : 127.0.0.1:9300"` or set `discovery.type: single-node` in `eleasticsearch.yml` file to avoid the production use error.
- Click [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html) for discovery and cluster formation settings.
- I have provided the detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030240/7317816).

Answer (score 13):

Elasticsearch 7 requires information to form a cluster. This is provided by the following two properties in elasticsearch.yml

`cluster.initial_master_nodes` : This is used to provide the initial set of nodes whose vote will be consider in master election process.

`discovery.seed_hosts` : This is used to provide the set of nodes which are master eligible. This should contain the name of all nodes which are master eligible.

So for example you are forming a cluster with three nodes : `n0`, `n1`, `n2` which are master eligible then you config will look something like this:

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["n0", "n1", "n2"]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["n0", "n1", "n2"]
```

Note: `cluster.initial_master_nodes` is used only once by elastic which is very first time of cluster formation.

For more detailed information read this [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/discovery-settings.html).

Comment: This answer is good general advice, but the answer to this specific question is to set `discovery.seed_hosts: ["aa.bbb.ccc.dd"]` or `discovery.seed_hosts: []`. Either is fine in a one-node cluster.

Comment: @DaveTurner You are right. If the OP wants to have only one node cluster, but I never got a clear answer for that when I asked about the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my answer from docker container perspective. I initially tried running 3 nodes of elasticsearch in a same cluster and then tried running only 1 and faced same issue. To resolve, I deleted docker volumes. Please note, my docker elasticsearch nodes had no data so there was no data loss due to docker volume deletion.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-my-config-file-should-be-on-publish-mode-with-a-single-node/189034