# Elasticsearch docker container in non-prod mode to eliminate vm.max_map_count=262144 requirement

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

How can I configure elasticsearch docker containers (elasticsearch:7.5.0) to use fewer resources and run in a nonproduction mode?

I want to run containers in Jenkins and on my desktop and am hitting the requirement from [this elastic doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-prod-prerequisites/docker.html#_set_vm_max_map_count_to_at_least_262144) for running docker images in production

I'd like to figure out how I can modify my elasticsearch.yml which I copy into the container to configure it to set the container into a less resource-intensive mode.

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I haven't yet.  I should be able to circle back to test in a few days.  Thanks for the info

Comment: Not only does that work, but it is also how our test lab environment scripts do it... and I wrote the orchestration of those and missed it.  This context is for our build machine and desktop testing.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Let's hope it helps the next person too

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can run your docker in development mode and create a single node ES cluster by following [official ES link on single node ES cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode). As mention in this link.

> To start a single-node Elasticsearch cluster for development or
>   testing, specify single-node discovery to bypass the bootstrap checks:

In-short all you need to do is add `-e "discovery.type=single-node"` in your docker command, which would enable the dev mode and then you don't have to satisfy the hard limits of production environments ie **it bypass bootstrap checks**.

More information on your settings and how to turn it off can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html#allow-mmap)

> node.store.allow_mmap. This is a boolean setting indicating whether or
>   not memory-mapping is allowed. The default is to allow it.

So, if `-e "discovery.type=single-node` env. doesn't turn it off, then you can explicitly set it false in your `elasticsearch.yml`.

Comment: I'm using elasticsearch 8.7.0 and spinning-up a container in a Jenkins pipeline, and I needed to set _both_ `discovery.type=single-node` and `node.store.allow_mmap=false`.

Answer (score 10):

If you're reading this trying to find out how to do it when using `docker-compose`:

#### With an environment key

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
  elasticsearch:
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
```

#### With a custom elasticsearch.yml

Create `elasticsearch.yml`:

```yaml
discovery:
  type: single-node
```

Mount it as a volume on your container in docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
  elasticsearch:
    volumes:
      - /path-to/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
```

Make sure the first part actually a path, it has to start with `/` or `./` or else it's going to treat it as a named volume. The second part is the path inside the container so it can be left as is.

The file must be in a location you've enabled File Sharing for in your Docker application. Set this up in Preferences > Resources > File Sharing if you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue when I was using this `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2` elastic-search docker image for a single node cluster.

The error I was getting is:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
```

**To start a single-node Elasticsearch cluster with Docker**

**Solution1**

So the solution would be to run a docker image with an environment variable `-e "discovery.type=single-node"` in docker run command.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

**Solution2**

Add this `"discovery.seed_hosts : 127.0.0.1:9300"` in eleasticsearch.yml file. And build your own docker image and use it.

`Dockerfile` will look like this.

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
RUN echo discovery.seed_hosts : 127.0.0.1:9300 >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml 
RUN cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

For more details click [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/docker.html).

Comment: I already provided the solution 1 in my answer and about the solution 2, I am not sure how it works, can you explain why it avoid the production checks and run it in dev mode ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Just now I have updated the answer and provided the `Dockerfile` so please have a look. Here we are using loopback address as seed_hosts so elastic search will then only be accessible from the host machine itself. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: why to make it complex?, simply using `discovery.type=single-node` skips the production checks and mentioned in elasticsearch config and has a lot of documentation around it.