# Elasticsearch 7.6 listening on loopback address but not on the server IP

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

1. when I do curl on localhost IP It is working but when I am doing it on node IP. It is showing the following error (curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.21.221:9200; Connection refused).
2. In netstat, the port is listening only on the loopback address

> [root@elk ~]# netstat -tnlpu | grep 9200
>       tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      14968/java
>       tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      14968/java

3. when I am applying following changes to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file and restart the elasticsearch service it is failing

> ```
> network.host: 0.0.0.0
> network.host: [_local_, _site_, _global_]
> network.host: 0.0.0.0
> network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
> network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
> ```

Comment: the host instead of 192.168.21.221

Comment: @sundeep its been a long time, can you please follow up on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Since OP didn't mention the error I am assuming that he tried adding the below configs which would have triggered the **production bootstrap checks** as `network.host: 0.0.0.0` means running in a production environment as you are not binding it to the loopback address.

Most probably OP must be getting below error:

> ERROR: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426167/4039431) bootstrap checks failed [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426167/4039431): the default discovery settings
>   are unsuitable for production use; at least one of
>   [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers,
>   cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

And to resolve it, add below config in `elasticsearch.yml`

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

More info on [single-node in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426167/4039431) and After this, if you get an issue related to VM memory then run below **command as a root user**.

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Please note after that command `netstat -tnlpu | grep 9200` shows it's not listening on the loopback address.

> tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*
>   LISTEN      17247/java

**You can also check it with your `curl <your-ip>:9200` command.**