# I cannot access Elasticsearch running on EC2 from the outside

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, connection-refused

I installed Elasticsearch from the following [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/targz.html#install-linux). Then, I modified the **/elasticsearch-7.17.17/config/elasticsearch.yml** file to set ***network.host:0.0.0.0***. Additionally, I opened port 9200 from the security group associated with the EC2 instance.

[image: inbound rules]

After that, when I make a request with `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/?pretty"`, I get the desired response. However, when I make a request with `curl -X GET "public_ip:9200/?pretty"`, I receive the error *

> "curl: (7) Failed to connect to public_ip port 9200 after 0 ms:
> Connection refused."

- Is there anything wrong or missing that I did? Thank you.

When i run `sudo netstat -lptun | grep 9200` command. I get a result like the following.[image]

**elastcisearch.yml**

```
 # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 0.0.0.0
 #
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
#
# ---------------------------------- Security ----------------------------------
#
#                                 *** WARNING ***
#
# Elasticsearch security features are not enabled by default.
# These features are free, but require configuration changes to enable them.
# This means that users don’t have to provide credentials and can get full access
# to the cluster. Network connections are also not encrypted.
#
# To protect your data, we strongly encourage you to enable the Elasticsearch security features.
# Refer to the following documentation for instructions.
#
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/configuring-stack-security.html
```

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755577/10692493

Comment: Your Elasticsearch security group needs to allow ingress from whatever public IP the client presents.

Comment: Already i added. Isn't that enough?

Comment: pls show the elasticsearch.yml to check the network level

Comment: I've added the Elasticsearch.yml to the question. It seems a bit strange to me that all lines are commented out, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the machine via the public IP? Are you sure the server is actually listening to 0.0.0.0? Because in the config you’ve provided, that line is commented out (#) and thus ignored for configuration

Comment: Yes, because I did the same thing in the Redis configuration on the same machine, and I can make requests to Redis from anywhere. But for Elasticsearch, it gives a connection refused error. @MichelFeldheim

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When i added **http.host: 0.0.0.0** to elasticsearch.yml the probleb fixed.