# Elasticsearch Docker container crashing with Error: Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have a simple docker setup in which, I pulled Elastic search from Docker Hub using the following command:

```
docker pull elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

Version code is mentioned since it's not working for the latest tag.

Then I created an ElasticSearch container using command:

```
docker container run -d -p 9200:9200 --name elasticsearch elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

After entering the above command the container is created and running but it ran for a couple of seconds and then it crashed with the error message: Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started.

Below is the complete Error JSON

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-04-07T19:28:05,721Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "c62b88f8807c", "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started" }
```

I googled and tried many links, I tried recreating the container, redownloading the image of a lower version, I even tried increasing memory in Docker > Settings > Resources > Advanced but still it did not work for me.

I have tried all options on following link: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25067

Please help, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426167/4039431 and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: It worked `docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" --name elasticsearch elasticsearch:7.6.2` worked for me, please post it as the answer so that I can accept and close it @OpsterElasticsearchNinja

Comment: Glad it worked :), posted answer as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you are running elasticsearch docker in development mode, you need to use `discovery.type=single-node` to avoid the production boot-strap checks, which is causing your docker to exit.

As mentioned in the comment adding `discovery.type=single-node` solved the issue and below is the complete command.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" --name elasticsearch elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

Comment: Ran this: docker run --name es01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.1 ... did not work