# run elasticsearch from docker on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, jvm

im trying to start a elasticsearch instance for dev porpuse(the smallest possible , dont care), is inside ec2 t2.micro (in order to avoid cost running the elasticsearch service from aws)

so ... i pulled the instance

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9
```

[image]

now , when i try to run the image

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9
```

the following error apperars

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 1073741824, 0) 

    failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 1073741824 bytes for committing reserved memory.
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # logs/hs_err_pid1.log
```

i heard in some places that you have two options 
Either give more memory to your VM (is this posible for a t2.micro instance), how can achive that?
 or change Elasticsearch JVM settings`/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and lower the values of the following parameters -Xms512m -Xmx512m but how can i do this if i the image its not available to get in

i also tried to install elasticserach via rpm but requires coreutils >= 8.4 , so another failure trying to get the instance up

using -Xms512m -Xmx512m on jvm.options with avaible space (i guess)
i got the same error **Not enough space**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are on right right track.  `t2.micro` instances only have 1 GiB of memory, so you either need to upgrade your VM or lower the JVM settings.

To bind mount the jvm options file, you can use the `-v` option.  So when starting the container, you would add something like this to the docker command:

```
<docker run command> -v local/jvm.options:/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9
```

Where `local/jvm.options` contains your specified JVM options as a file on the EC2 instance.

For more information about bing mounting, you can see the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Comment: i did run 
sudo docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9 -v local/jvm.options:/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option
error =>  basename: invalid option -- 'v'
where local/jvm.options  has -Xms521m -Xmx521m

Comment: Move the -v option before the image name: sudo docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node"  -v local/jvm.options:/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.9

Comment: Also, local/jvm.options was just an example, you can use any file name you want.  Just make sure you give the absolute path.

Comment: could you please check the last updated at the bottom?  the docker comman runs and i guess with available space but i got the same error of space

Comment: @GuillermoNahuelVarelli, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589254/why-docker-image-with-elasticsearch-status-restarting-always answers your question.