# About docker container's exit when docker-compose up

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch with docker.

And you can see the guide here -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

my docker-compose.yml  below

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - node.name=master-node
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es-data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
      - 127.0.0.1:9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.name=data-node1
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1"
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9301:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es-data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  es-data01:
    driver: local
  es-data02:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
   # driver: bridge
```

the problem is

> 1. I cannot connect by `curl -XGET localhost:9200`
> 2. docker container exits automatically after few seconds

can you help me?

ps : when I try `docker run` it works. what is the difference between them?

`docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name elasticsearch -it --rm -v els:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0`

Comment: I found some clue.

when `docker run` without `-e "discovery.type=single-node"` option

container exits too... but don't know why

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer and links provided in that, let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the container logs by using `docker logs <your stopped container-id>`, here you can get the container id using `docker ps -a` command.

Also please follow [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421343/elasticsearch-docker-container-in-non-prod-mode-to-eliminate-vm-max-map-count-26/60426167#60426167) and s[et the memory requirements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html)
which would help you run the Elasticsearch in docker. if it doesn't help then provide the logs which you can get as explained earlier.

Based on comments adding the updated `docker-compose`

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - node.name=master-node
      - node.master=true
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "cluster.initial_master_nodes=master-node"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es-data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
      - 127.0.0.1:9300:9300
    networks:
      - elastic
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - node.name=data-node1
      - node.master=false
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "cluster.initial_master_nodes=master-node"
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9301:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - es-data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  es-data01:
    driver: local
  es-data02:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
   # driver: bridge
```

Comment: I found these error logs

`max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]` and `the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured`

Comment: great so you have two issues, first will be solved by https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html and another I am pinging soon.

Comment: Thanks for help, memory problem solved. Can you help second error?

Comment: @JS_Kim, yeah doing that

Comment: OK, I'll try it. I guess.. the added line assigns master-node? so make link between two nodes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214799/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-js-kim).

Answer (score 1):

As you are following this article, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

worth checking the second section with limits and memory resources as the containers in docker-compose is exiting due to low resources.

Answer (score 1):

`Exited with code 137` error is because of resource limitation (usually RAM) on the host machine. You can resolve this problem by adding this line to the environment variables of your docker-compose file:

```
- "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

You can read more about heap size settings, on official Elasticsearch documentation, in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings) link.